# Splitting rows of a column to different columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge

[{'id': 'cef8bab0-8482-4086-bc8f-29bf229f13f6'},
 {'createdAt': '2018-12-18T16:09:57.098Z',
  'notes': 'Candidate initial submission.',
  'createdBy': 'Steven Klinger'},
 {'createdAt': '2018-12-18T23:14:09.415Z',
  'notes': 'The Candidate Status has now been updated from **CV Submitted** and **Feedback Pending** to **Client CV Review** and **Feedback Awaiting**',
  'createdBy': 'Matt'},
 {'createdAt': '2019-01-22T16:04:46.958Z',
  'notes': 'The Candidate Status has now been updated from **Client CV Review** and **Feedback Awaiting** to **Client CV Review** and **Position on Hold**',
  'createdBy': 'Matt'}]df.pivot(index='id', columns='createdAt', values='notes')`[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have a dataframe that has 4 columns:`id`,`status`,`createdAt`and`createdBy`. For one id, there are 3 or 4 or 12 or n numbers of status in the`status`column. The index for every new id in the`id` column starts with 0. I need to split these statuses from rows to columns.

The resulting dataframe will look like : `id`, `status0`, `status1`, `status2` and so on; `createdAt0`, `createdAt1`, and so on; `createdBy0`, `createdBy1`, and so on.

Comment: Please share some code, it would be easier to understanf your DF structure than with text ;)

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output dataframes.

Comment: i added the sample input, output i need. i dont have output :D

Comment: Please add your example DataFrame not as an image, but as text.

Comment: The `status` column is missing in your example

Comment: i am unable to add in text, thats why added image

Comment: @MEdwin , notes = status

Comment: okay, I get it now. It would be really difficult recreating your dataframe with pictures you have. You will get quicker help if you can use a simplified version in text to show which logic you want get assistance from.

Comment: @MEdwin , i think its related to unpivot , but when i am setting my index as id , i am getting error , saying index has duplicates.

Comment: True... I can see your index with 1, 0, and then 1, 0, Index needs to be unique.

Comment: what exactly is in df… can you share that with us? some samples

Comment: @MEdwin so how to do it now, if i will reset index, will the elements in rows be same? u can do it. i am new, and an intern working with nested json.

Comment: I think the real issue is that your `json` data source is nested and you might need to normalise it. Can you try `json_normalize`. or share with us  two rows of the `json` entry to see the content.

Comment: i have normalized it.

Comment: Very good and the next stage might also involve flattening...

Comment: yes i have done , this dataframe i got from a column called candidateNotes notes that has list of nested dictionaries, id were in other column. now for each id a table is needed that will show notes , time at which this note was created, by whom it was created. so column names in resulting dataframe will be 'id' , 'createdAt0' , 'createdAt1' ,....'createdAtn','note0', 'note1',....'noteN', 'createdBy0', 'createdBy1' ....'createdByN'.

Comment: hmmm... I still think you are missing the logic in the presentation. it should really be for each unique id, different/multiple 'createdBy', 'notes' entries instead

Comment: so can u help me ?

Comment: @MEdwin now see i have uploaded input in text

Comment: very good. I got it. from what I have seen. It seems you are not loading the `json` data properly. There is a disconnect between the `Id` and the rest of the data (`createdAt`,`createdBy`, `notes`). You really need to look at the `json` loading to dataframe logic. May be share the original `json` content

Comment: @MEdwin ,give me your email

Comment: @MEdwin ok so can u tell me how to merge both dictionaries that are inside same list?